# Workflow Service (xamlx) using AppFabric not persisting

Tags: wcf, workflow, workflowservice, workflow-services

I installed Appfabric Hosting Services. I created a xamlx Workflow Service. The workflow service sends emails based on a user's schedule. The Appfabric Persistence was working, but I unknowingly must have changed something, because it stopped persisting in the Appfabric database. The Workflow Service still works as long as I don't do an iisreset, which makes sense because the workflow is hosted in IIS.

I uninstalled AppFabric and re-installed it. In my root web.config, the InstanceStore is defined:

```
<instanceStores>
            <add name="defaultSqlPersistenceStore" provider="SqlPersistenceStoreProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServerWorkflowInstanceStoreConnectionString" />
        </instanceStores>
```

And the connectionStringName is defined. When I go to IIS and select the web application, I select configure from the Manage WCF and WF Services, and go to the Workflow Persistence tab. I select SQL Server Workflow Persistence and the SQL Server store drop down list is empty. If I select the computer name on the right in IIS and click Configure to setup Workflow Persistence, the defaultSqlPersistenceStore from above is in the drop down list. But that still doesn't help my Workflow service. In my Workflow Service web.config, I have:

```
<behavior name="Scheduler">
                <sqlWorkflowInstanceStore instanceCompletionAction="DeleteAll" instanceEncodingOption="GZip" instanceLockedExceptionAction="BasicRetry" connectionStringName="WorkflowPersistenceStore" hostLockRenewalPeriod="00:00:30" runnableInstancesDetectionPeriod="00:00:05" />                    
                <workflowInstanceManagement authorizedWindowsGroup="AS_Administrators" />
                <workflowUnhandledException action="AbandonAndSuspend" />
                <workflowIdle timeToPersist="00:01:00" timeToUnload="00:01:00" />
            </behavior>
```

I tried adding a store to the WF service web.config:

```
<microsoft.applicationServer>
    <persistence>
        <instanceStores>
            <add name="storeA" provider="SqlPersistenceStoreProvider" connectionStringName="WorkflowPersistenceStore" />                
        </instanceStores>
    </persistence>
</microsoft.applicationServer>
```

and I'm able to select it in IIS - Configure WCF and WF Services, but my WF Service still doesn't persist.

When I check the Persistence database tables, the WF Service isn't even registered. (SELECT * FROM [System.Activities.DurableInstancing].[ServiceDeploymentsTable]). When persistence was working, there was a record with the WF Service url.

Thanks in advance,

-jason